# Error: Your JAVA_HOME is invalid: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_73

Tags: java, android, windows, ionic

Tengo un error al tratar de compilar mi apk usando el comando

`ionic build android`

El error pienso que se genero cuando java mando la actualizacion el dia de hoy y se quedo como a medio instalar, el error es este:

```
Error: Failed to run "java -version", make sure that you have a JDK installed.
You can get it from: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads.
Your JAVA_HOME is invalid: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_73
```

Me dice que corra el comando `java -version`, para asegurarme si esta instalado el jdk, y me lanza el siguiente error:

```
Error: could not open `C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_91\lib\i386\jvm.cfg'
```

Instale la versión de java mas reciente, pero al parecer hubo algún error en la instalación. Dejo aquí una captura de la consola

[image: imagen_consola]

Answer (score 2):

En cuanto al error:

> Error: Your JAVA_HOME is invalid: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_73

Este error puede ser relacionado a que no esta especificado correctamente el path en las variables de ambiente o no tienes instalado el JDK.

Pero me llama la atención el mensaje que obtienes al ejecutar desde la linea de comandos `java -version` :

> Error: could not open `jvm.cfg'

**Esto puede ser causado por no instalar Java que no corresponde a tu arquitectura tal vez instalaste por error el de 32-bit y necesitas de 64-bit o viceversa.**

No se si sea un caso drástico el que haya corrompido, como sea el caso sería buena idea reinstalaras nuevamente.

Comment: Si eso hare eliminare todo, y reinstalare de nuevo, y listo asi me evito cualquier problema, por que yo lo unico que hice fue actualizar no descargue nada de ningun lado, el mismo lo hizo

Answer (score 1):

Intenta el siguiente procedimiento<sup><s>*</s></sup> para desinstalar Java manualmente, para luego instalarlo:

1. Eliminar el contenido de `C:\Program Files\Java` o `C:\Program Files (x86)\Java` (según sea el caso).
2. Eliminar el contenido del directorio `%UserProfile%\LocalLow\Oracle\Java`.
3. Eliminar el contenido del directorio `%UserProfile%\LocalLow\Sun\Java\`.
4. Eliminar la ruta `C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath` de la variable `PATH`.
5. Ejecutar [Microsoft Fix it utility](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/17588/fix-problems-that-block-programs-from-being-installed-or-removed).
6. Descargar e instalar [Java SE Development Kit 8u102](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html).
7. Actualizar o añadir la variable `JAVA_HOME` a `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_102` o `C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_102` (según sea el caso).

<sup>─────────────

**<s>*</s>** **Limitación de responsabilidad**: En ningún caso el autor de la respuesta será responsable de ninguna reclamación, daños u otras responsabilidades, ya sea en un litigio, agravio o de otro modo, que surja de o en conexión con este procedimiento o el uso u otro tipo de acciones en el procedimiento.</sup>

Comment: Quien voto en contra podria explicar la razón de su voto

Comment: Gracias Paul, voy a probar eso fue lo que se me paso, reinstalar todo el java y listo peor antes desintalar limpiando todo bien

Answer (score -1):

Para poder verificar el JAVA_HOME seguiremos los proximos pasos en windows:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]